# How to mimic this using RESTSHARP C# restclient instead of using httpclient?

Tags: c#, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I am using httpclient to invoke a endpoint , this is working fine for me. But i need to invoke the endpoint using the restsharp restclient object. How can i do that? Here is the code that works for me using the http client  postasync.

//Input Parameters and request headers

```
 string userID = "testuser";
        string memberId = "001";
        string baseURL = "https://www.test.com";
        string urlParameters ="TestServices/GetAll/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}";
        string contentType = "application/json";
        string role = "USER";
        string Caller = "PREVIEW";
        string ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string systemId = "613e70b3-e3ec-4205-bcd6-094d6a9f7a41";

        string encryptedToken = “XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”
        string sessionID = "8303d34a-5c8a-4984-9bf9-4ba39be21352";
```

//data to be send as stringcontent

```
        string postData = "{\"TheContentAreas\":[{\"ControlTypeID\":\"230c5669-aa0d-41bc-9069-559b5e7d0ece\",\"PlaceholderID\":\"a16a471e-9416-43fc-8ceb-fddb97509e0c\"}]}";

        string response = string.Empty;
```

//call the end point

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Session", sessionID);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("EncryptedKey", encryptedToken);


        try
        {
           HttpResponseMessage resp = client
                .PostAsync(string.Format(urlParameters, role, systemId, Caller, ticks, userID, memberId),
                   new StringContent(postData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

          if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
                response = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have a look: http://restsharp.org/ and https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Have you even attempted to do this with RestSharp before asking? If not, why?

Comment: Todd- Why was not your question like  did you try this? If yes please post your code here. :) . Just Kidding. I already resolved this. Posting my solution.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time working on it, here is my solution.

I created a generic service invoker class and called it from my main class.

```
//Main class calling the service invoker
try
{
    var _restMethodInvoker = new RestEndPointInvoker();

    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Authorization", "xxx" },
        { "Session", "xxx" } ,
        { "EncryptedKey", "xxx"}
    };

    var inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Role", "MEMBER" },
        { "SystemID", "xxx" } ,
        { "Caller", "PREVIEW" } ,
        { "Ticks", "1234" } ,
        { "UserID", "TestUser" } ,
        { "MemberId", "TestMEmber" }   

    var request1 = new RestClientRequest
    {
        _apiMethod = "TestServices/GetAll/{Role}/{SystemID}/{Caller}/{Ticks}/{UserID}/{MemberId}",
        _environmentType = "xx",
        _inputParameters = inputParameters,
        _requestHeaders = headers
    };

    var result1 = _restMethodInvoker.GetAsync<List<ReturnType>>(request1);

    var result = result1.Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Rest Invoker class using restsharp

```
namespace RestServiceInvoker
{
    public class RestEndPointInvoker : IRestEndPointInvoker 
    {               
        public RestEndPointInvoker()
        {
            _httpClient = new RestClient();        
        }


        private void BuildRestClient(RestClientRequest request)
        {          
                //Set the  headers             
            foreach (var header in request._requestHeaders)
            {
                _httpClient.AddDefaultHeader(header.Key, header.Value);
            }                
        }


        public async Task<IRestResponse<T>> GetAsync<T>(RestClientRequest request) where T: new()
        {
            //Build the client object
            BuildRestClient(request);

            //Build request object
            var restRequest = BuildRestReqestObject(request);

            //var response11 = _httpClient.Execute<T>(restRequest);

            var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();

            //Execute the request
            _httpClient.ExecuteAsync<T>(restRequest, response =>
            {
                if (response.ErrorException != null)
                    taskSource.TrySetException(response.ErrorException);
                else
                    taskSource.TrySetResult(response);
            });

            return await taskSource.Task;
        }

        private RestRequest BuildRestReqestObject(RestClientRequest requestObj)
        {          
            var request = new RestRequest {Resource = requestObj._apiMethod};

            if (requestObj._inputParameters == null || requestObj._inputParameters.Count <= 0) return request;

            foreach (var inputParam in requestObj._inputParameters)
            {
                request.AddParameter(inputParam.Key, inputParam.Value, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            }

            request.Method = Method.POST;  //This could be parameterized from the client. For now we are only supporting get calls

            //This would be sent as input parameter. Just was lazy to hardcode it here
            string jsonToSend = @"xxxxxxxxxxx";

            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonToSend, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            return request;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of awaiting the `TaskCompletionSource` task in `GetAsync<T>` you should return the task itself and await it at a higher level.

Comment: Also, by using `throw ex` in your calling code `catch` block - you are discarding the original stack trace.

Comment: I agree. Thanks Colin for the feedback.